# EJB Timer Service: order of timeouts with same ScheduleExpression

Tags: java, timeout, ejb

I have many tasks that are using the same ScheduleExpression. But my problem is that is necessary an order to execute each one. Can I tell for the Timer Service an execution order?

Note: Tasks don't have persistence

Thanks in advance,

Adelar

Comment: I think the container is calling all of them "at the same time". I would propably make a singleton bean that the scheduled tasks can ask who should execute next.

Comment: But on second thought. If centralizing the knowledge of execution order into on place, one might as well handle the timeout in one place..

Comment: I have changed de ScheduleExpression to increment 1 second by task... its something like workaround, but until now did work (25 minutes from now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case all tasks are using the same ScheduleExpression, doing all tasks to execute in the "same time". A workaround was to increment 1 second by task received to force a order.